# What is this strange javascript use for?

Tags: javascript, security

I am not sure if I can ask this question here but:

I have a JavaScript block which I don't understand:

```
var _0x3a04=["$(3C).4Z(2(){3 o=\x2218\x22,y=\x224r\x22,u=\x223F.\x22,s=\x223v\x22,t=\x22.3D\x22,x=\x223G\x22,w=\x223o\x22,q=\x22.m\x22,p=\x222s\x22,l=q+p,v=\x224H\x22,z=\x223q\x22,r=\x223B\x22;5($(\x22.2s\x22+y+\x22x\x22).1d(\x22a\x22).2M(o)==\x221g://\x22+u+\x22i\x22+s+\x22h\x22+r+\x22s.1D\x22\x26\x26$(\x22.2s\x22+y+\x22x\x22).1d(l).2M(o)==\x221g://\x22+x+\x22r-s\x22+w+\x22.3t\x22+v+\x22t\x22+t+\x22m\x22){1m.3A=(2(){3 a=2(c){3 f=c||{},b=f.1Z||1m.21.2a,g=f.3k||\x221g://1.2q.2g.1D/-2w/2x/2y/2C/2E/2H.2o\x22,d=f.4C||50,e=f.3m||0;(2(j){3 h=j(\x22#1E-2n-3y\x22),k=h.1d(\x22:2m\x22);h.2A(\x27\x3C12 3E=\x222n-1x\x22\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x27);3 i=j(\x22#2n-1x\x22);h.2F(\x223H\x22,2(){3 m=k.4i();i.4q().15(\x221M...\x22);j.1E({1w:\x221g://\x22+b+\x22/1O/2l/1C?1v=1X-1f-20\x26q=\x22+m+\x22\x262k-22=2B\x22,1s:\x2224\x22,26:\x2227\x22,28:2(I){3 H=I.1B.2e,E,D,G,F,A=\x22\x22;5(H!==1Q){A=\x22\x3C1r\x3E3w 22 1a 3z \x262D;\x22+m+\x22\x262D;\x3C/1r\x3E\x22;A+=\x27\x3Ca 11=\x221U\x22 18=\x22/\x22\x3E\x262j;\x3C/a\x3E\x3C2J\x3E\x27;1a(3 C=0;C\x3CH.16;C++){3 n=46 4a(m,\x224f\x22),G=H[C].1G.$t.1i(n,\x22\x3C25\x3E\x22+m+\x22\x3C/25\x3E\x22);1a(3 B=0;B\x3CH[C].14.16;B++){5(H[C].14[B].1n==\x2229\x22){F=H[C].14[B].18}}5(\x221A\x221f H[C]){E=H[C].1A.$t}17{5(\x221C\x221f H[C]){E=H[C].1C.$t}17{E=\x22\x22}}E=E.1i(/\x3C\x5CS[^\x3E]*\x3E/g,\x22\x22);5(E.16\x3Ee){E=E.1y(0,e)+\x22...\x22}E=E.1i(n,\x22\x3C25\x3E\x22+m+\x22\x3C/25\x3E\x22);5(\x222f$1H\x221f H[C]){D=H[C].2f$1H.1w.1i(/\x5C/s[0-9]+\x5C-c/g,\x22/s\x22+d+\x22-c\x22)}17{D=g}A+=\x27\x3C7\x3E\x3Ca 18=\x22\x27+F+\x27\x22 1K=\x221L\x22\x3E\x3C13\x3E\x3C1N 2p=\x22\x27+d+\x27\x22 1b=\x22\x27+d+\x27\x22 1P=\x22\x27+D+\x27\x22/\x3E\x3C/13\x3E\x3Cb\x3E\x27+G+\x22\x3C/b\x3E\x3C/a\x3E\x3Cp\x3E\x22+E+\x22\x3C/p\x3E\x3C/7\x3E\x22}A+=\x22\x3C/2J\x3E\x22;i.15(A)}17{i.15(\x27\x3Ca 11=\x221U\x22 18=\x22/\x22\x3E\x262j;\x3C/a\x3E\x3C1h\x3E1R 1x!\x3C/1h\x3E\x27)}},1S:2(){i.15(\x27\x3Ca 11=\x221U\x22 18=\x22/\x22\x3E\x262j;\x3C/a\x3E\x3C1h\x3E1T 4p 1B.\x3C/1h\x3E\x27)}});1j 1t});h.2F(\x224s\x22,\x22.1U\x22,2(){i.4x();1j 1t})})(1c)};1j 2(b){a(b)}})();1m.4D=(2(){3 a=2(A){3 d=A||{},h=d.1Z||1m.21.2a,n=d.4G||8,g=d.3f||\x22#3g\x22,e=d.3h||3i,c=d.3j||1W,f=d.3l||4,b=d.3n||2G,m=d.3p||1Y,j=d.3r||1t,k=d.3s||\x222I\x22,i=d.3u||\x221g://1.2q.2g.1D/-2w/2x/2y/2C/2E/2H.2o\x22;$.1E({1w:\x221g://\x22+h+\x22/1O/2l/2h?1v=1X-1f-20\x262k-22=\x22+n+\x22\x22,1s:\x2224\x22,26:\x2227\x22,28:2(G){3 I,B,H,K,M,J,D=\x22\x22,L=G.1B.2e;5(L!==1Q){5(j){D=\x22\x3C1e 11=\x272U 2V\x27\x3E\x22}17{D=\x22\x3C1e 11=\x272V\x27\x3E\x22}1a(3 F=0;F\x3CL.16;F++){1a(3 E=0;E\x3CL[F].14.16;E++){5(L[F].14[E].1n==\x2229\x22){I=L[F].14[E].18;1q}}1a(3 C=0;C\x3CL[F].14.16;C++){5(L[F].14[C].1n==\x222Y\x22\x26\x26L[F].14[C].1s==\x222m/15\x22){H=L[F].14[C].1G.30(\x22 \x22)[0];1q}}5(\x221A\x221f L[F]){K=L[F].1A.$t}17{5(\x221C\x221f L[F]){K=L[F].1C.$t}17{K=\x22\x22}}5(\x222f$1H\x221f L[F]){M=L[F].2f$1H.1w.1i(/\x5C/s[0-9]+\x5C-c/g,\x22/s\x22+e+\x22-c\x22)}17{M=i}K=K.1i(/\x3C\x5CS[^\x3E]*\x3E/g,\x22\x22);5(K.16\x3Ec){K=K.1y(0,c)+\x22...\x22}B=L[F].1G.$t;J=L[F].31.$t.1y(0,10),J=J.1i(/-/g,\x22/\x22);D+=\x27\x3C7\x3E\x3C12 11=\x2247\x22\x3E\x3Ca 18=\x22\x27+I+\x27\x22 1K=\x221L\x22\x3E\x3C13\x3E\x3C1N 1v=\x22\x27+B+\x27\x221P=\x22\x27+M+\x27\x22/\x3E\x3C/13\x3E\x3C/a\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x3C12 11=\x2248\x22\x3E\x3C1r\x3E\x3Ca 18=\x22\x27+I+\x27\x22 1K=\x221L\x22\x3E\x27+B+\x27\x3C/a\x3E\x3C/1r\x3E\x3C12 11=\x2236\x22\x3E\x3C13 11=\x2237\x22\x3E\x27+J+\x27\x3C/13\x3E\x3C13 11=\x223a\x22\x3E\x27+H+\x22 \x22+k+\x27\x3C/13\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x3C12 11=\x224o\x22\x3E\x27+K+\x22\x3C/12\x3E\x3C/7\x3E\x22}D+=\x22\x3C/1e\x3E\x22;$(g).15(D);(2(N){N.2u.2v=2(O,Q,P){O=O||4;Q=Q||2z;P=P||1Y;1j 19.2b(2(){3 X=N(19),W=1F,V=[],U=O,R=X.1d(\x22\x3E 7:2i\x22).1b(),T=0;2 S(){5(W){3 Y=N(V[U]).1u({1b:0,1o:0}).2K(X);X.1d(\x22\x3E 7:2L\x22).1p({1o:0},P,2(){Y.1p({1b:R},P).1p({1o:1},P);N(19).23()});U++;5(U\x3E=T){U=0}}2N(S,Q)}X.1d(\x22\x3E 7\x22).2b(2(){V.2O(\x22\x3C7\x3E\x22+N(19).15()+\x22\x3C/7\x3E\x22)});T=V.16;X.2P(\x27\x3C12 11=\x223x\x22 /\x3E\x27).2Q().1u({1b:R*O});X.1d(\x22\x3E 7\x22).2R(\x22:2S(\x22+(O-1)+\x22)\x22).23();X.1k(\x221J\x22,2(){W=1t}).1k(\x221I\x22,2(){W=1F});S()})}})(1c);1c(2(){5(j){1c(\x221e.2U\x22).2v(f,b,m).1k(\x222W\x22,2(){1c(19).2c(\x221J\x22)}).1k(\x222X\x22,2(){1c(19).2c(\x221I\x22)})}})}17{$(g).15(\x22\x3C13\x3E1R 1x!\x3C/13\x3E\x22)}},1S:2(){$(g).15(\x22\x3C1h\x3E1T 1M 2r!\x3C/1h\x3E\x22)}})};1j 2(b){a(b)}})();1m.3I=(2(){3 a=2(B){3 e=B||{},k=e.1Z||1m.21.2a,c=e.3J||\x22#3K\x22,m=e.3L||6,j=e.3M||3N,i=e.3O||1t,b=e.3P||4,h=e.3Q||2G,g=e.3R||1Y,f=e.3S||1W,A=e.3T||\x221g://4.2q.2g.1D/-3U/3V/3W/3X/3Y/3Z-40-41.42\x22,n=e.43||50,d=e.44||\x22\x22;$.1E({1w:\x221g://\x22+k+\x22/1O/45/2h?1v=1X-1f-20\x22,1s:\x2224\x22,26:\x2227\x22,28:2(Q){3 I,K=Q.1B.2e;5(K!==1Q){I=\x22\x3C1e 11=\x272Z\x27\x3E\x22;1V=0;1a(3 H=0;H\x3Cn;H++){3 G,M,J,C,L,E;5(H==K.16){1q}5(1V\x3E=m){1q}3 P=K[H];1a(3 F=0;F\x3CP.14.16;F++){5(P.14[F].1n==\x2229\x22){G=P.14[F].18}}1a(3 O=0;O\x3CP.1z.16;O++){M=P.1z[O].49.$t;J=P.1z[O].32$4b.1P}5(M!=d\x26\x261V\x3Cm){1V++;I+=\x22\x3C7\x3E\x22;5(J==\x221g://4c.4d.1D/1N/4e.2o\x22){C=A}17{C=J.1i(/\x5C/s[0-9]+(\x5C-c|\x5C/)/,\x22/s\x22+j+\x22$1\x22)}3 E=(P.1z[0].33)?P.1z[0].33.$t:\x22#4g\x22;I+=\x27\x3C12 11=\x224h\x22\x3E\x3Ca 1n=\x2234\x22 18=\x22\x27+E+\x27\x22\x3E\x3C1N 1P=\x22\x27+C+\x27\x22 1v=\x22\x27+M+\x27\x22 2p=\x22\x27+j+\x27\x22 1b=\x22\x27+j+\x27\x22/\x3E\x3C/a\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x27;3 L=P.32$4j[1].4k;I+=\x27\x3C12 11=\x224l\x22\x3E\x3Ca 1n=\x2234\x22 18=\x22\x27+G+\x27\x22\x3E\x27+M+\x22\x3C/a\x3E \x3C13\x3E\x22+L+\x22\x3C/13\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x22;3 N=P.1A.$t;3 D=N.1i(/(\x3C([^\x3E]+)\x3E)/4m,\x22\x22);5(D!=\x22\x22\x26\x26D.16\x3Ef){D=D.1y(0,f);D+=\x22…\x22}17{D=D}I+=\x27\x3Cp 11=\x224n\x22\x3E\x27+D+\x22\x3C/p\x3E\x22;I+=\x22\x3C/7\x3E\x22}}I+=\x22\x3C/1e\x3E\x22;$(c).15(I);(2(R){R.2u.35=2(S,U,T){S=S||4;U=U||2z;T=T||1Y;1j 19.2b(2(){3 1l=R(19),2d=1F,Z=[],Y=S,V=1l.1d(\x22\x3E 7:2i\x22).1b(),X=0;2 W(){5(2d){3 38=R(Z[Y]).1u({1b:0,1o:0}).2K(1l);1l.1d(\x22\x3E 7:2L\x22).1p({1o:0},T,2(){38.1p({1b:V},T).1p({1o:1},T);R(19).23()});Y++;5(Y\x3E=X){Y=0}}2N(W,U)}1l.1d(\x22\x3E 7\x22).2b(2(){Z.2O(\x22\x3C7\x3E\x22+R(19).15()+\x22\x3C/7\x3E\x22)});X=Z.16;1l.2P(\x27\x3C12 11=\x224t\x22 /\x3E\x27).2Q().1u({1b:V*S});1l.1d(\x22\x3E 7\x22).2R(\x22:2S(\x22+(S-1)+\x22)\x22).23();1l.1k(\x221J\x22,2(){2d=1t}).1k(\x221I\x22,2(){2d=1F});W()})}})(1c);1c(2(){5(i){1c(\x221e.2Z\x22).35(b,h,g).1k(\x222W\x22,2(){1c(19).2c(\x221J\x22)}).1k(\x222X\x22,2(){1c(19).2c(\x221I\x22)})}})}17{$(c).15(\x22\x3C13\x3E1R 1x!\x3C/13\x3E\x22)}},1S:2(){$(c).15(\x22\x3C1h\x3E1T 1M 2r!\x3C/1h\x3E\x22)}})};1j 2(b){a(b)}})();1m.4u=(2(){3 a=2(d){3 g=d||{},b=g.1Z||1m.21.2a,f=g.4v||8,e=g.4w||\x22#2t\x22,h=g.4y||1F,c=g.4z||\x222I\x22;$.1E({1w:\x221g://\x22+b+\x22/1O/2l/2h?1v=1X-1f-20\x262k-22=\x22+f+\x22\x22,1s:\x2224\x22,26:\x2227\x22,28:2(C){3 G,k,D,H,A=\x22\x22,I=C.1B.2e;5(I!==1Q){A=\x22\x3C1e\x3E\x22;1a(3 E=0;E\x3CI.16;E++){1a(3 B=0;B\x3CI[E].14.16;B++){5(I[E].14[B].1n==\x2229\x22){G=I[E].14[B].18;1q}}1a(3 m=0;m\x3CI[E].14.16;m++){5(I[E].14[m].1n==\x222Y\x22\x26\x26I[E].14[m].1s==\x222m/15\x22){D=I[E].14[m].1G.30(\x22 \x22)[0];1q}}k=I[E].1G.$t;H=I[E].31.$t.1y(0,10);H=H.1i(/-/g,\x22/\x22);A+=\x27\x3C7\x3E\x3C1r\x3E\x3Ca 18=\x22\x27+G+\x27\x22 1K=\x221L\x22\x3E\x27+k+\x27\x3C/a\x3E\x3C/1r\x3E\x3C12 11=\x2236\x22\x3E\x3C13 11=\x2237\x22\x3E\x27+H+\x27\x3C/13\x3E\x3C13 11=\x223a\x22\x3E\x27+D+\x22 \x22+c+\x22\x3C/13\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x3C/7\x3E\x22}A+=\x22\x3C/1e\x3E\x22;$(e).15(A);5(h){2 F(){$(\x22#2t 1e 7:2i\x22).1p({1o:0},4A,2(){$(19).4B($(\x22#2t 1e\x22)).1u(\x221o\x22,1)})}3 n=3b(2(){F()},3c);$(e).4E(2(){4F(n)},2(){3b(2(){F()},3c)})}}17{$(e).15(\x22\x3C13\x3E1R 1x!\x3C/13\x3E\x22)}},1S:2(){$(e).15(\x22\x3C1h\x3E1T 1M 2r!\x3C/1h\x3E\x22)}})};1j 2(b){a(b)}})()}17{$(z).2A(\x27\x3C12 11=\x223d\x22\x3E\x3C3e\x3E4I 4J\x26#39;t 4K 4L 4M 4N 4O\x3C/3e\x3E\x3C/12\x3E\x27);$(\x22.3d\x22).1u({4P:\x224Q\x22,4R:\x220\x22,4S:\x224T 0 0 0\x22,\x224U-4V\x22:\x224W%\x22,\x22z-4X\x22:\x222B\x22,\x224Y-2T\x22:\x2251\x22,2p:\x221W%\x22,1b:\x221W%\x22,2T:\x2252\x22})}});","|","split","||function|var||if||li||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||class|div|span|link|html|length|else|href|this|for|height|jQuery|find|ul|in|http|strong|replace|return|bind|ab|window|rel|opacity|animate|break|h4|type|false|css|alt|url|result|substring|author|content|feed|summary|com|ajax|true|title|thumbnail|start|stop|target|_blank|Loading|img|feeds|src|undefined|No|error|Error|close|ntotal|100|json|1000|url_blog|script|location|results|remove|get|mark|dataType|jsonp|success|alternate|host|each|trigger|aa|entry|media|blogspot|default|first|times|max|posts|text|search|gif|width|bp|Feed|kr|isibreakingnews|fn|simpleSpy|htG7vy9vIAA|Tp0KrMUdoWI|AAAAAAAABAU|5000|append|9999|e7XkFtErqsU|quot|s1600|on|4000|grey|Comments|ol|prependTo|last|attr|setTimeout|push|wrap|parent|filter|gt|color|spyrcp|recntpst|mouseenter|mouseleave|replies|rcomnetspy|split|published|gd|uri|nofollow|simpleSpyRkm|datex|dt|ac||cm|setInterval|3000|errorx|h1|id_cintainrp|rcentpost|thumbSize|70|contjumlah|srcBlank|limitspy|summaryLength|intervalspy|ite|tickspeed|body|animatedRecentPost|cmtext|blo|pBlank|vyt|Search|spyWrapper|form|keyword|searchxx|eme|document|co|id|www|mk|submit|rccommnetsx|id_containrc|rcentcomnets|numComments|avatarSize|60|animatedRecentcomments|limitspyrkm|intervalspyrkm|tickspeedrkm|characters|defaultAvatar|AEWksK942OE|UFiyLzXJhiI|AAAAAAAAFKE|jBegaGPClxI|s70|user|anonymous|icon|png|maxfeeds|adminBlog|comments|new|thumbp|titlexp|name|RegExp|image|img1|blogblog|blank|ig|nope|kmtimg|val|extendedProperty|value|ketkomt|gi|komtsum|contxisi|loading|show|edit|click|spyWrapperrkm|breakingnews|breakingpostx|id_breaking|fadeOut|animatedBreaking|breakingcmtext|200|appendTo|scrthumbSize|rccpostsx|hover|clearInterval|numpostx|gspo|Please|Don|Remove|or|change|Credit|Link|position|fixed|top|padding|150px|font|size|120|index|background|ready||black|white","","fromCharCode","replace","\x5Cw+","\x5Cb","g"];eval(function (_0x1995x1,_0x1995x2,_0x1995x3,_0x1995x4,_0x1995x5,_0x1995x6){_0x1995x5=function (_0x1995x3){return (_0x1995x3<_0x1995x2?_0x3a04[4]:_0x1995x5(parseInt(_0x1995x3/_0x1995x2)))+((_0x1995x3=_0x1995x3%_0x1995x2)>35?String[_0x3a04[5]](_0x1995x3+29):_0x1995x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0x3a04[4][_0x3a04[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0x1995x3--){_0x1995x6[_0x1995x5(_0x1995x3)]=_0x1995x4[_0x1995x3]||_0x1995x5(_0x1995x3);} ;_0x1995x4=[function (_0x1995x5){return _0x1995x6[_0x1995x5];} ];_0x1995x5=function (){return _0x3a04[7];} ;_0x1995x3=1;} ;while(_0x1995x3--){if(_0x1995x4[_0x1995x3]){_0x1995x1=_0x1995x1[_0x3a04[6]]( new RegExp(_0x3a04[8]+_0x1995x5(_0x1995x3)+_0x3a04[8],_0x3a04[9]),_0x1995x4[_0x1995x3]);} ;} ;return _0x1995x1;} (_0x3a04[0],62,313,_0x3a04[3][_0x3a04[2]](_0x3a04[1]),0,{}));
```

What is it used for? How can such code be written?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's obfuscated JavaScript.

If you don't know, where it is coming from, it is most likely your site was hacked and this JavaScript is malicious!

> What is it used for? How can such code be written?

It is used to hide your code. The reason may be different: Some think they can protect their own code by such things. This, however, is futile as you can see below. Another usecase is for hackers to hide their code from detection. People who often use scripts found on the internet might not see, that this code is invalid and think it is part of some script they wanted to use. Furthermore it hinders the automatic detection of malicious scripts for the same reasons.

As for how to do it, check out this question: [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194397/1169798)

---

The somehow un-obfuscated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var o = "href",
        y = "edit",
        u = "www.",
        s = "vyt",
        t = ".co",
        x = "mk",
        w = "ite",
        q = ".m",
        p = "kr",
        l = q + p,
        v = "gspo",
        z = "body",
        r = "eme";
    if ($(".kr" + y + "x").find("a").attr(o) == "http://" + u + "i" + s + "h" + r + "s.com" && $(".kr" + y + "x").find(l).attr(o) == "http://" + x + "r-s" + w + ".blo" + v + "t" + t + "m") {
        window.searchxx = (function () {
            var a = function (c) {
                var f = c || {}, b = f.url_blog || window.location.host,
                    g = f.srcBlank || "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.gif",
                    d = f.scrthumbSize || 50,
                    e = f.summaryLength || 0;
                (function (j) {
                    var h = j("#ajax-search-form"),
                        k = h.find(":text");
                    h.append('<div id="search-result"></div>');
                    var i = j("#search-result");
                    h.on("submit", function () {
                        var m = k.val();
                        i.show().html("Loading...");
                        j.ajax({
                            url: "http://" + b + "/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&q=" + m + "&max-results=9999",
                            type: "get",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            success: function (I) {
                                var H = I.feed.entry,
                                    E, D, G, F, A = "";
                                if (H !== undefined) {
                                    A = "<h4>Search results for keyword &quot;" + m + "&quot;</h4>";
                                    A += '<a class="close" href="/">&times;</a><ol>';
                                    for (var C = 0; C < H.length; C++) {
                                        var n = new RegExp(m, "ig"),
                                            G = H[C].title.$t.replace(n, "<mark>" + m + "</mark>");
                                        for (var B = 0; B < H[C].link.length; B++) {
                                            if (H[C].link[B].rel == "alternate") {
                                                F = H[C].link[B].href
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if ("content" in H[C]) {
                                            E = H[C].content.$t
                                        } else {
                                            if ("summary" in H[C]) {
                                                E = H[C].summary.$t
                                            } else {
                                                E = ""
                                            }
                                        }
                                        E = E.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g, "");
                                        if (E.length > e) {
                                            E = E.substring(0, e) + "..."
                                        }
                                        E = E.replace(n, "<mark>" + m + "</mark>");
                                        if ("media$thumbnail" in H[C]) {
                                            D = H[C].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g, "/s" + d + "-c")
                                        } else {
                                            D = g
                                        }
                                        A += '<li><a href="' + F + '" target="_blank"><span><img width="' + d + '" height="' + d + '" src="' + D + '"/></span><b>' + G + "</b></a><p>" + E + "</p></li>"
                                    }
                                    A += "</ol>";
                                    i.html(A)
                                } else {
                                    i.html('<a class="close" href="/">&times;</a><strong>No result!</strong>')
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                i.html('<a class="close" href="/">&times;</a><strong>Error loading feed.</strong>')
                            }
                        });
                        return false
                    });
                    h.on("click", ".close", function () {
                        i.fadeOut();
                        return false
                    })
                })(jQuery)
            };
            return function (b) {
                a(b)
            }
        })();
        window.rccpostsx = (function () {
            var a = function (A) {
                var d = A || {}, h = d.url_blog || window.location.host,
                    n = d.numpostx || 8,
                    g = d.id_cintainrp || "#rcentpost",
                    e = d.thumbSize || 70,
                    c = d.contjumlah || 100,
                    f = d.limitspy || 4,
                    b = d.intervalspy || 4000,
                    m = d.tickspeed || 1000,
                    j = d.animatedRecentPost || false,
                    k = d.cmtext || "Comments",
                    i = d.pBlank || "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.gif";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://" + h + "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + n + "",
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (G) {
                        var I, B, H, K, M, J, D = "",
                            L = G.feed.entry;
                        if (L !== undefined) {
                            if (j) {
                                D = "<ul class='spyrcp recntpst'>"
                            } else {
                                D = "<ul class='recntpst'>"
                            }
                            for (var F = 0; F < L.length; F++) {
                                for (var E = 0; E < L[F].link.length; E++) {
                                    if (L[F].link[E].rel == "alternate") {
                                        I = L[F].link[E].href;
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                                for (var C = 0; C < L[F].link.length; C++) {
                                    if (L[F].link[C].rel == "replies" && L[F].link[C].type == "text/html") {
                                        H = L[F].link[C].title.split(" ")[0];
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                                if ("content" in L[F]) {
                                    K = L[F].content.$t
                                } else {
                                    if ("summary" in L[F]) {
                                        K = L[F].summary.$t
                                    } else {
                                        K = ""
                                    }
                                }
                                if ("media$thumbnail" in L[F]) {
                                    M = L[F].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g, "/s" + e + "-c")
                                } else {
                                    M = i
                                }
                                K = K.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g, "");
                                if (K.length > c) {
                                    K = K.substring(0, c) + "..."
                                }
                                B = L[F].title.$t;
                                J = L[F].published.$t.substring(0, 10), J = J.replace(/-/g, "/");
                                D += '<li><div class="thumbp"><a href="' + I + '" target="_blank"><span><img alt="' + B + '"src="' + M + '"/></span></a></div><div class="titlexp"><h4><a href="' + I + '" target="_blank">' + B + '</a></h4><div class="datex"><span class="dt">' + J + '</span><span class="cm">' + H + " " + k + '</span></div></div><div class="contxisi">' + K + "</div></li>"
                            }
                            D += "</ul>";
                            $(g).html(D);
                            (function (N) {
                                N.fn.simpleSpy = function (O, Q, P) {
                                    O = O || 4;
                                    Q = Q || 5000;
                                    P = P || 1000;
                                    return this.each(function () {
                                        var X = N(this),
                                            W = true,
                                            V = [],
                                            U = O,
                                            R = X.find("> li:first").height(),
                                            T = 0;

                                        function S() {
                                            if (W) {
                                                var Y = N(V[U]).css({
                                                    height: 0,
                                                    opacity: 0
                                                }).prependTo(X);
                                                X.find("> li:last").animate({
                                                    opacity: 0
                                                }, P, function () {
                                                    Y.animate({
                                                        height: R
                                                    }, P).animate({
                                                        opacity: 1
                                                    }, P);
                                                    N(this).remove()
                                                });
                                                U++;
                                                if (U >= T) {
                                                    U = 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                            setTimeout(S, Q)
                                        }
                                        X.find("> li").each(function () {
                                            V.push("<li>" + N(this).html() + "</li>")
                                        });
                                        T = V.length;
                                        X.wrap('<div class="spyWrapper" />').parent().css({
                                            height: R * O
                                        });
                                        X.find("> li").filter(":gt(" + (O - 1) + ")").remove();
                                        X.bind("stop", function () {
                                            W = false
                                        }).bind("start", function () {
                                            W = true
                                        });
                                        S()
                                    })
                                }
                            })(jQuery);
                            jQuery(function () {
                                if (j) {
                                    jQuery("ul.spyrcp").simpleSpy(f, b, m).bind("mouseenter", function () {
                                        jQuery(this).trigger("stop")
                                    }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
                                        jQuery(this).trigger("start")
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        } else {
                            $(g).html("<span>No result!</span>")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(g).html("<strong>Error Loading Feed!</strong>")
                    }
                })
            };
            return function (b) {
                a(b)
            }
        })();
        window.rccommnetsx = (function () {
            var a = function (B) {
                var e = B || {}, k = e.url_blog || window.location.host,
                    c = e.id_containrc || "#rcentcomnets",
                    m = e.numComments || 6,
                    j = e.avatarSize || 60,
                    i = e.animatedRecentcomments || false,
                    b = e.limitspyrkm || 4,
                    h = e.intervalspyrkm || 4000,
                    g = e.tickspeedrkm || 1000,
                    f = e.characters || 100,
                    A = e.defaultAvatar || "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-AEWksK942OE/UFiyLzXJhiI/AAAAAAAAFKE/jBegaGPClxI/s70/user-anonymous-icon.png",
                    n = e.maxfeeds || 50,
                    d = e.adminBlog || "";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://" + k + "/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script",
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (Q) {
                        var I, K = Q.feed.entry;
                        if (K !== undefined) {
                            I = "<ul class='rcomnetspy'>";
                            ntotal = 0;
                            for (var H = 0; H < n; H++) {
                                var G, M, J, C, L, E;
                                if (H == K.length) {
                                    break
                                }
                                if (ntotal >= m) {
                                    break
                                }
                                var P = K[H];
                                for (var F = 0; F < P.link.length; F++) {
                                    if (P.link[F].rel == "alternate") {
                                        G = P.link[F].href
                                    }
                                }
                                for (var O = 0; O < P.author.length; O++) {
                                    M = P.author[O].name.$t;
                                    J = P.author[O].gd$image.src
                                }
                                if (M != d && ntotal < m) {
                                    ntotal++;
                                    I += "<li>";
                                    if (J == "http://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif") {
                                        C = A
                                    } else {
                                        C = J.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c|\/)/, "/s" + j + "$1")
                                    }
                                    var E = (P.author[0].uri) ? P.author[0].uri.$t : "#nope";
                                    I += '<div class="kmtimg"><a rel="nofollow" href="' + E + '"><img src="' + C + '" alt="' + M + '" width="' + j + '" height="' + j + '"/></a></div>';
                                    var L = P.gd$extendedProperty[1].value;
                                    I += '<div class="ketkomt"><a rel="nofollow" href="' + G + '">' + M + "</a> <span>" + L + "</span></div>";
                                    var N = P.content.$t;
                                    var D = N.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
                                    if (D != "" && D.length > f) {
                                        D = D.substring(0, f);
                                        D += "…"
                                    } else {
                                        D = D
                                    }
                                    I += '<p class="komtsum">' + D + "</p>";
                                    I += "</li>"
                                }
                            }
                            I += "</ul>";
                            $(c).html(I);
                            (function (R) {
                                R.fn.simpleSpyRkm = function (S, U, T) {
                                    S = S || 4;
                                    U = U || 5000;
                                    T = T || 1000;
                                    return this.each(function () {
                                        var ab = R(this),
                                            aa = true,
                                            Z = [],
                                            Y = S,
                                            V = ab.find("> li:first").height(),
                                            X = 0;

                                        function W() {
                                            if (aa) {
                                                var ac = R(Z[Y]).css({
                                                    height: 0,
                                                    opacity: 0
                                                }).prependTo(ab);
                                                ab.find("> li:last").animate({
                                                    opacity: 0
                                                }, T, function () {
                                                    ac.animate({
                                                        height: V
                                                    }, T).animate({
                                                        opacity: 1
                                                    }, T);
                                                    R(this).remove()
                                                });
                                                Y++;
                                                if (Y >= X) {
                                                    Y = 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                            setTimeout(W, U)
                                        }
                                        ab.find("> li").each(function () {
                                            Z.push("<li>" + R(this).html() + "</li>")
                                        });
                                        X = Z.length;
                                        ab.wrap('<div class="spyWrapperrkm" />').parent().css({
                                            height: V * S
                                        });
                                        ab.find("> li").filter(":gt(" + (S - 1) + ")").remove();
                                        ab.bind("stop", function () {
                                            aa = false
                                        }).bind("start", function () {
                                            aa = true
                                        });
                                        W()
                                    })
                                }
                            })(jQuery);
                            jQuery(function () {
                                if (i) {
                                    jQuery("ul.rcomnetspy").simpleSpyRkm(b, h, g).bind("mouseenter", function () {
                                        jQuery(this).trigger("stop")
                                    }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
                                        jQuery(this).trigger("start")
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        } else {
                            $(c).html("<span>No result!</span>")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(c).html("<strong>Error Loading Feed!</strong>")
                    }
                })
            };
            return function (b) {
                a(b)
            }
        })();
        window.breakingnews = (function () {
            var a = function (d) {
                var g = d || {}, b = g.url_blog || window.location.host,
                    f = g.breakingpostx || 8,
                    e = g.id_breaking || "#isibreakingnews",
                    h = g.animatedBreaking || true,
                    c = g.breakingcmtext || "Comments";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://" + b + "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + f + "",
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (C) {
                        var G, k, D, H, A = "",
                            I = C.feed.entry;
                        if (I !== undefined) {
                            A = "<ul>";
                            for (var E = 0; E < I.length; E++) {
                                for (var B = 0; B < I[E].link.length; B++) {
                                    if (I[E].link[B].rel == "alternate") {
                                        G = I[E].link[B].href;
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                                for (var m = 0; m < I[E].link.length; m++) {
                                    if (I[E].link[m].rel == "replies" && I[E].link[m].type == "text/html") {
                                        D = I[E].link[m].title.split(" ")[0];
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                                k = I[E].title.$t;
                                H = I[E].published.$t.substring(0, 10);
                                H = H.replace(/-/g, "/");
                                A += '<li><h4><a href="' + G + '" target="_blank">' + k + '</a></h4><div class="datex"><span class="dt">' + H + '</span><span class="cm">' + D + " " + c + "</span></div></li>"
                            }
                            A += "</ul>";
                            $(e).html(A);
                            if (h) {
                                function F() {
                                    $("#isibreakingnews ul li:first").animate({
                                        opacity: 0
                                    }, 200, function () {
                                        $(this).appendTo($("#isibreakingnews ul")).css("opacity", 1)
                                    })
                                }
                                var n = setInterval(function () {
                                    F()
                                }, 3000);
                                $(e).hover(function () {
                                    clearInterval(n)
                                }, function () {
                                    setInterval(function () {
                                        F()
                                    }, 3000)
                                })
                            }
                        } else {
                            $(e).html("<span>No result!</span>")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(e).html("<strong>Error Loading Feed!</strong>")
                    }
                })
            };
            return function (b) {
                a(b)
            }
        })()
    } else {
        $(z).append('<div class="errorx"><h1>Please Don&#39;t Remove or change Credit Link</h1></div>');
        $(".errorx").css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "0",
            padding: "150px 0 0 0",
            "font-size": "120%",
            "z-index": "9999",
            "background-color": "black",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            color: "white"
        })
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

To the question on how to un-obfuscate:

I just need one tool and that's the development console of a browser, e.g., Firebug.

Then search the code above for the call of `eval()`. Here it was just called once, sometimes it is called multiple times (even recursive calls can happen). Replace each occurrence of `eval()` with something like `console.log()`. That way instead of running the code, it is just printed to the console.

Then run it through an online js-beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ and you have the above code.

Comment: @Alex From a first glance,  a whole new page gets loaded and inserted to the current document.

Comment: wow your good, how did you do that, what tool?

Comment: @Alex See my edit for an explanation.

Comment: @Alex simply remove the eval from the code and you get the unobfuscated script as a string which then would be evaluated.

Comment: Sirko, Christoph, hats off to you both, cheers.